# Functions has access to it own lexical as well outer environment

Tags: javascript, function, lexical-scope, lexical-closures

Functions has access to it own lexical as well outer environment but it's not working or maybe I don't understand why it's working like that.

Here is the code

```
function makeArmy() {
    let shooters = [];
  
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
      let shooter = function() {
        console.log( i );
      };
      shooters.push(shooter);
      i++;
    }

    return shooters;
  }
  
  let army = makeArmy();
  
  // all shooters show 10 instead of their numbers 0, 1, 2, 3...
  army[0](); // 10 from the shooter number 0
  army[1](); // 10 from the shooter number 1
  army[2](); // 10 ...and so on.
```

Fixed code

```
while (i < 10) {
      let j = i; // added variable to while loop (lexical  environment)
      let shooter = function() { 
        alert( j );
      };
    shooters.push(shooter);
    i++;
  }
```

But why don't it work like this when i define variable with J inside the function! Shooter function has it's own lexical environment.

```
while (i < 10) {
      let shooter = function() {
      let j = i; // define J inside function but still it gives 10 why?
        console.log( j );
      };
      shooters.push(shooter);
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: Your variable `i` is declared **outside** the `while` loop. Thus all the constructed functions in the loop share the same `i`, and at the end of the loop its value is 10.

Comment: But we define j variable within the function and now it has variable store inside it lexical scope. Why it's not reference that j? What di mean by the constructed function?

Comment: The function you make with the function expression in the loop. It relies on a reference to `i`, and `i` is that variable declared with `let` before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you *define* the variable `j` inside of the function (`let j`), you aren't *initializing* that variable (`j = i`) until the function gets executed.

At the time when the function instance is created, the reference to the outer variable `i` is "closed over," so the function can access the value of `i` when it gets executed. But it's not executed until after you've completed the loop, so `let j = i` causes `j` to have the same value that `i` has at the *end* of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of the same code but simpler

```js
let x = 0
const a = []
a.push(() => console.log(x))
{
  // creates a new variable
  const y = x
  a.push(() => console.log(y))
}
// x is changed but y is not
x = 1
// prints 1
a[0]()
// prints 0
a[1]()
```

Comment: This shows why the "fix" works, but it doesn't explain why the final code snippet doesn't work, with a variable declared _inside_ of one of the lambda expressions.